# DBMS_SQL.describe_columns causes ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to PL/SQL. I am trying to get the following procedure to run at work. The call to DBMS_SQL.describe_columns is causing "ORA-29471: DBMS_SQL access denied" to be thrown. How do I fix this? I read that some functions and procedures within the DBMS_SQL package can throw this error when given an invalid cursor id, but I am using that cursor id in calls to that package prior to the line that fails. So, I don't know how the cursor id could be invalid.

```
procedure ExecuteQuery (
      pio_report        IN OUT reports_dictionary_tab%ROWTYPE
      , pi_rpt_params   in out Report_Params2_obj
      , pi_vars         vchar100_tab_ty
      , pi_binds        vchar100_tab_ty
      , po_cursor       out gv_rc
      , po_columnDesc   out DBMS_SQL.desc_tab
      , pi_debug boolean default gv_debug
) is
    lv_rows integer;--Ignore return, not valid for SELECT or DDL, only DML.
    lv_columnCount integer; --Not sure if this is needed outside of this
    lv_cursorid integer;
begin

    lv_cursorid := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
    
    DBMS_SQL.parse( c => lv_cursorid, statement => pio_report.query, language_flag => dbms_sql.native);

    
    --set the bind variables...
    begin
        for b in 1..pi_vars.count loop
            DBMS_SQL.bind_variable ( c => lv_cursorid, name => pi_binds (b), value => pi_vars (b));
        end loop;

    exception
        when others then
            DebugOut( pi_table_name => 'Binds', pi_table => pi_binds , pi_debug => pi_debug);
            DebugOut( pi_table_name => 'Values', pi_table => pi_vars , pi_debug => pi_debug);
    end;

    --Ignore the row count coming back, it is undefined
    --for SELECT statements
    lv_rows := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE (lv_cursorid);

    po_cursor := dbms_sql.to_refcursor(lv_cursorid);

    -- this line fails
    DBMS_SQL.describe_columns( c=> lv_cursorid, col_cnt => lv_columnCount , desc_t => po_columnDesc );

    for c in 1..po_columnDesc.count loop

        case po_columnDesc(c).col_type

            when gv_type_varchar then dbms_sql.define_column( c=> lv_cursorid, position => c, column => gv_datatype_varchar, column_size => gv_vchar2_col_size );
            when gv_type_char then dbms_sql.define_column( c=> lv_cursorid, position => c, column => gv_datatype_varchar, column_size => gv_vchar2_col_size );
            when gv_type_number then dbms_sql.define_column( c=> lv_cursorid, position => c, column => gv_datatype_number );
            when gv_type_date then dbms_sql.define_column( c=> lv_cursorid, position => c, column => gv_datatype_date );
            when gv_type_tstamp_tz then dbms_sql.define_column( c=> lv_cursorid, position => c, column => gv_datatype_tstamp_tz );
            when gv_type_clob then dbms_sql.define_column( c=> lv_cursorid, position => c, column => gv_datatype_clob );
            else DebugOut ( pi_text => 'Unknown Column type '||po_columnDesc(c).col_type||' for "'||po_columnDesc(c).col_name||'"' , pi_debug => pi_debug);
        end case;

    end loop; --End Column Definition Loop

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-6006977D-A65B-4E47-87F6-4B704FFD6732):

> Once the cursor_number is transformed into a REF CURSOR, the cursor_number is no longer accessible by any DBMS_SQL operations.

It will run if you move the line

```
    po_cursor := dbms_sql.to_refcursor(lv_cursorid);
```

to the end of the procedure. I'm not sure quite what you're trying to achieve though...